# Firebase cloud firestore: How to prevent rogue fields?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The firebase documentation makes it easy to check for the existence of child records:

```
".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'age'])"
```

How do you construct a rule to make sure any new data ONLY has these 'name' and 'age' fields?

Comment: That database rule allows fields two be written other than name and age.  It just requires that the two exist, at the very least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
allow create: if (['name', 'age'].hasAll(request.resource.data.keys()) &&
    request.resource.data.size() == 2
```

Only two keys are allowed, and they must be name and age.

See the [Firestore security rules reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules) to learn more about what all you can do in rules, and the data types of the things you're working with.

Comment: Or for even more sophisticated validation consider cloud-functions.

Comment: @ArtjomZabelin Cloud Functions can't stop bad data from getting into your database.  The best it can do is delete bad data after it's been created.

Comment: Hmm ... so you have a feature request right there :D a beforeWrite/Update trigger

Comment: @ArtjomZabelin There will never be any sort of "before" triggers in Cloud Functions.  That's not the way the system works.  Serverless environments work by sending your function events that represent changes already made to your project.  It's out of scope for functions to intercept changes to products.